# How do I get Google Analytics data for teaching college course?

Tags: education

Does anyone know how I can obtain a Google Analytics database for teaching undergraduates how to work with Google Analytics?
I don't have a commercial website which I can attach to, and I want to explore some of the more advanced campaigns and tagging options for tracking purposes.

Seems like a "Chicken & Egg" problem, and thus far Google staff have been useless in answering this query.

Comment: Are you looking for open data?

Comment: Set up your own website specifically for this purpose, and then have your students access it prior to the course?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for open data.  @JanDoggen I could set up my own website, but it's non-trivial to "replicate" customer journeys across pages simulating actions,  or to investigate "attribution"

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are looking for open datasets for the google analytics data of a website.

Generally, companies don't release that data as it includes tracking data and sensitive data.

However, you can get some of the open datasets from the site [data.gov](http://www.data.gov/) of a site called lacity.org.

[Link to the list of datasets](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=google%20analytics&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc)

Comment: thank you very much for the useful link to the open data sets.  Yes I know virtually no commercial company will release tracking data (too bad we can't get data from bankrupt companies in Google's archives).  I looked at the data.gov website .... looks promising.  I'll try to import some CSV data into Google to see what I get and then post my experience(s) here.

Comment: Tried importing LAcity.org dataset into Google Analytics.  Unfortunately the free license version of analytics does not allow most fields to be mapped and imported such as page view counts.  So, I'm still looking for some other solutions - short of building own website and "forcing" students to create data by visiting the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Analytics demo account: https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/demoAccount

I hope this helps.